# M2Crypto.RSA.RSAError: data greater than mod len?

Tags: python, cryptography

```
def geekso_decrypt_with_private_key (message, pk_loc):
    pk = RSA.load_key ('ca.key') # load RSA for decryption
    try:
        decrypted = pk.private_decrypt (message, RSA.pkcs1_padding)
        decrypted = base64.b64decode (decrypted)
    except RSA.RSAError as e:
        return "ERROR decrypting" + e.message
    return decrypted
```

Error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "cipher.py", line 82, in geekso_decrypt_with_private_key
    decrypted = pk.private_decrypt (message, RSA.pkcs1_padding)
  File "/home/abhi/stark/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/M2Crypto/RSA.py", line 82, in private_decrypt
    return m2.rsa_private_decrypt(self.rsa, data, padding)
M2Crypto.RSA.RSAError: data greater than mod len
```

While decryption above error coming

how to resolve above issue?

Comment: My answer is updated to have a sample.

Answer (score 0):

There is a limitation based on key size in RSA standardization. Take a look at [RFC3447 (section 7.2.2 Decryption operation)](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3447.txt) for more details.
Here is the quote from standards:

> Input:
>
> K:        recipient's RSA private key
>
> C:        ciphertext to be decrypted, an octet string of length k
>
> where k is the length in octets of the RSA modulus n
>
> Output:
>
> M        message, an octet string of length at most k - 11

So you need to check message size in your implementation to meet standard. For example for 2048-bit RSA key the maximum length of the plaintext is 1960 bits.

Here is the calculation for sample:

`2048 bits = 256 octets`

so: `k = 256` and then: `k-11 = 245 bytes = 1960 bits`

Make sure your key size supports plaintext size.